Syncfusion Flutter Chart: Bar Chart Inverts with Logarithmic Y-Axis (< 1 Values)
I'm encountering an issue with inverted bars in my Syncfusion Flutter chart. When using a logarithmic y-axis and data values all less than 1, the bars appear to grow downwards instead of upwards. This is visually misleading and doesn't accurately represent my data.
Here's my code snippet:
class Values {
  final String x;
  final double y;

  Values(this.x, this.y);
}

List<Values> getChartData() {
  return [
       Values('CFI', 0.3),
    Values('CC', 0.1),
    Values('BLC', 0.03),
    Values('BDA', 0.01),
  ];
}

SfCartesianChart(
  title: ChartTitle(text: "Bar Graph"),
  primaryXAxis: const CategoryAxis(
    title: AxisTitle(
      text: 'Headers',
      textStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 20, 63)),
    ),
  ),
  primaryYAxis: const LogarithmicAxis(
    title: AxisTitle(
      text: 'Values',
      textStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 20, 63)),
    ),
  ),
  series: <CartesianSeries>[
    ColumnSeries<Values, String>(
      dataSource: getChartData(),
      xValueMapper: (Values course, _) => course.x,
      yValueMapper: (Values course, _) => course.y,
      dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 20, 63),
      pointColorMapper: (Values data, _) => data.y < 20 ? Colors.red : Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 20, 63),
    ),
  ],
)

This is the output from the code  :
Inverted bar graphs 
Initially, I tried setting the isInverted property of the logarithmic axis in my Syncfusion Flutter chart to invert the bars. This successfully flipped the bars, but it also inverted the y-axis itself. Now, the y-axis displays values from highest to lowest, which isn't the desired behavior.
isInverted =true
I noticed that values below 1 on the y-axis were plotted in an inverted way. To fix this, I tried setting the minimum value of the logarithmic axis to the lowest data point in my chart. However, this didn't resolve the inverted bar issue.
When logarithmic y axis is set to the lowest data point value

I would like to let you know, that the logarithm of 1 is 0, for decimal data points less than 1, such as 0.1 or 0.01, are used, they will result in negative values on the logarithmic axis. This is because the logarithm of 0.1 is -1, and the logarithm of 0.01 is -2. This behavior is an expected behavior.
Furthermore, we have verified this behavior using Microsoft Excel with logarithmic axis and the Excel produces results similar to those in our charts when decimal values less than 1 are used. For reference, we have attached the output of a logarithmic axis in Excel.
Excel output for logarithmic axis:

